# Why does it say I've already raised a "duplicate" flag?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636428/group-formation-in-tennis-tournament-using-python) for being unclear, and then noticed that the OP is re-asking a question that was put on hold yesterday (and with far less information). However, when I went to flag it as a duplicate, it says

> you have already raised this type of flag

for both the "it is a duplicate..." and "it should be closed for another reason..." options. What's going on here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only flag the question for *any type of closure* (i.e. Too Broad, Unclear, Off-Topic, duplicate and Primarily Opinion based) once.  You can't flag the question separately for multiple different close reasons.

Stick a comment on the question along the lines of:

> Possible duplicate of [link goes here]

Someone else may close it as a duplicate.  Although honestly, if it's closed for some reason other than being a duplicate, that's fine too.

Comment: Adding the comment worked.

Comment: If it gets closed for some reason other than being a duplicate and if that's fine, then why all the big hoohaa about close banners and helping the OP to understand why his question has been closed? I thought we were all about "directing them to the answer", which will only happen with a dupe if it's actually marked as such?

Comment: I'm getting this "bug" when I don't flag as duplicate.  I flag as primarily opinion based, and if I click on the flag link again I get "you have already raised this type of flag" under "it is a duplicate" and "it should be closed for another reason", but I didn't raise it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Poldie If you've flaged for any type of closure you cannot flag for any type of closure again.

Comment: @Servy I don't want to try that out and mess anything up, and I'm not doubting you at all, but if that's the case why do I see a mixture of ghosted and clickable options? Seems like a bit of a car crash to me; if i can't select anything again, ghost them all out, not the one I selected and some other option which I didn't select?