# Change the “you have already raised this type of flag” label

Tags: feature-request, flags

When I flag a question for close (duplicate or other reasons), I cannot flag it for close again with another reason, which is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Other flags are still available (leading to e.g. deletion), but the close options are grayed-out in the form and provided with a label saying “you have already raised this type of flag”.

[image: Image of the form with two “you have already raised this type of flag” labels]

**The wording of the label is what bothers me.** It looks like I issued two flags – one for duplicate, one for another close reason. I find it confusing and at least [two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254706/2157640) [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265522/2157640) people did before me. **Can it be changed to something that makes clear that “this type of flags” means “flag for close”?** Adding a frame (HTML `<fieldset>`?) around both the options and showing just one label at its top would work too.

<sub>The confusion is even deeper-rooted. “it should be closed for another reason…” does not make clear that it means “other reason than duplicate”. Without deeper understanding of the system and deeper thought, it looks like spam and offensive are close reasons too. Maybe this issue can be addressed in another meta question. Maybe even the order of options would deserve a discussion if it has not taken place yet. I’m not discussing these issues now, anyway.</sub>

Comment: @iStimple Thank you for the link. Another case where confusion from the label pops up. And another solution: instead of a frame I suggested, create the impression of block by adding the label before and after the two options.

Comment: I humbly suggest to change the label text to "you have already raised a flag for closing". Something like that. I was confused, too, because of the word "type". What are "flag types"? So I guess it depends on the consequence of the respective flag, and I think this should be made clear.