# SO claims that I used a flag, that I didn't

Tags: support, flags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26506196/1469208) just poped in my review queue and I flagged it as off-topic, because seeking for an opinion. I have then opened question page, added a comment and again tired to flag it. To my surprise, SO didn't allow me to flag this question as duplicate, claiming, that I have already flagged it like that:

[image]

That's completely not true. I have never flagged this question as duplicate of anything. What is going on?

Comment: This is a dup, but can't find it...  You already flagged for closure as off-topic.  A duplicate flag is just another type of close flag.  Just like I can't vote to close twice, you can't flag to close again for another reason.

Comment: The repeated reporting of this issue proves that the UI is confusing.

Comment: @psubsee2003 ^^^ this one? Also, there's [Change the “you have already raised this type of flag” label](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267779/change-the-you-have-already-raised-this-type-of-flag-label) feature request

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you have used a flag of that type.

Flags are split into three types:

1. Spam/Offensive
2. Off topic - includes duplicate, should be migrated as well as the other off topic reasons.
3. Other.

So by flagging is as "off topic -> opinion based" you've "used up" your off topic flag. If you think about it a question can't be closed as both a duplicate and opinion based. You chose one so the other choices *within that type* are now unavailable to you.